# Tails of function and Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-tails

I have a questions about Fourier transforms of functions in general.
Let $f$ be a function and $\phi$ its Fourier transform. If $f$ has fat tails, must $\phi$ then necessarily have thin tails? Conversely, if $f$ has thin (slowly decaying) tails, must $\phi$ then necessarily have fat tails?

Comment: More like smoothness of one is equivalent to thin tails of the other. The two tails are not related.

Comment: The Schwartz space is closed under Fourier transforms. All functions there have quite thin tails, decaying faster than $|x|^{-n}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}.$